# Pass value of user input in HTML to jQuery.Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to pass a value from a user input in a html to `jQuery.ajax`. Here's the code for my JS file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({           
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myurl.aspx',
        data: {
            action: 'something', 
            count: txtCount
        }
    });
});
```

and here's my html file:

```html
Count: <input type="text" id="txtCount" name="count" />
<input id="btnSubmit" type="Submit" value="Submit" />
<div> output somewhere here</div>
```

My javascript is working, I just removed some of the codes since i'm just pointing out on how to pass the values from the html to my ajax. I'm trying to develop a Chrome Packaged App.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val

Comment: i know the .val().. i'm new to jQuery and ajax, i don't know how to make it work... i tried different things, creating function inside the function and even inside the ajax, still not working,.. i started jQuery 2days ago by the way

Comment: `count: $('#txtCount').val()`

Comment: thanks for the immediate reply, hmm, your comment is correct, but i get error, and i don't know how to debug on the runtime

Comment: aaah now it's working thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({           
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'myurl.aspx',
    data: {
        action: 'something', 
        count: $("#txtCount").val();
    }
});
```

Comment: the comment answered it first so i'll just vote 1 up for you :) thanks for the reply sir.